# How to clone a project from Bitbucket into Intellij IDEA?

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea, bitbucket, intellij-plugin

I tried **VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Bitbucket** (Bitbucket plugin).

IDE shows the following:

> ```
> Login to Bitbucket ...
> Getting list of repositories ...
> ```

That's all. No dialog boxes with a selection of the repository.

I would be grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is/was a bug in the third-party BitBucket plug-in. See [Plugin does not work well with IDEA 13](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/issue/56/solved-plugin-does-not-work-well-with-idea) A comment on that report indicates that the plug-in is not actively being maintained. But one of the [community members](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/issue/56/solved-plugin-does-not-work-well-with-idea#comment-7599495) did create a patch for it and has an alternative build of the plug-in available for download.

That said, **you can clone a bitbucket repository without the BitBucket plug-in**. You do not mention if the repo is a Git or Mercurial repo (as BitBucket supports both). But if you configure Mercurial ang Git (see [Bitbucket 201 Bitbucket with Git and Mercurial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+201+Bitbucket+with+Git+and+Mercurial)) you can just clone it via *VCS > Checkout from Version Control > Mercurial* or VCS > *Checkout from Version Control > Git.* Just use the HTTPS or SSH URL shown in the "Clone" tab for the repository on bitbucket.

Comment: Dear @Javaru, unfortunately the link to "Bitbucket 201 Bitbucket with Git and Mercurial" is broken. An updated link (for Git) is this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/copy-your-git-repository-and-add-files-746520876.html